# Creating Command to Search Excel Database for Existing User (Using OleDb on Visual Basic with Windows Form)

Tags: vb.net, oledb

everybody! :)

I am currently developing a sign-in program for my mentoring organization. I've been slowly teaching myself coding through Visual Basic, and so far have some progress with signing-in users. I am trying to determine how to input a command to search the Excel file I'm connected with for a user ID (OneCard ID) to see if a user already exists and doesn't need to register with the system. This is my code thus far:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Register

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand

    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

        cn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source =C:\Users\mn582\source\repos\VBTest.xls;extended properties=excel 8.0;"
        cn.Open()

        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "insert into [Register Data$]values('" & OneCard.Text & "','" & FirstName.Text & "','" & LastName.Text & "')"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With
        cn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome, " & FirstName.Text & "!")

        OneCard.Text = String.Empty
        FirstName.Text = String.Empty
        LastName.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
        Close()
        LiabilityForm.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I would really appreciate any advice on how to create a command for finding existing user ID's. I've searched here and on other websites, and am not sure what to do.

Thank you, everybody. :)

Comment: Start more basic. Have you successfully pulled any data from an excel sheet? If not, start there. Once you have that working the rest should follow. If you can't get that working or after it is working, you have trouble getting the next bit, then ask a specific question along the lines of "I want X to happen but Y is happening instead, what is wrong with this code." ... this kind of question usually gets better responses AND you will learn more this way. :)

Comment: Hello, Roger! Thank you so much for your comment, and I'm sorry for my delay. For the current form I'm using, I'm not pulling data, but rather inputting it into an Excel file (like it's a database). The data from the form I'm making is saving to the file, however I just am not sure how to get started with coding a command to look-up the Excel file to verify if a username is already present. I can try to do this and then post another question once I have some code down. Do you have any suggestions on what I could do? I was reading SQL commands may help, but not sure. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Here's a couple links. SO question that MAY be a duplicate of this question. This solution requries excel to be installed locally. If 
that isn't assumed, be sure to mention in your new question. (also I recommend deleting this one until you have a more precise question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230445/find-specific-data-in-excel-sheet-using-vb-net

MSFT article that they used for source info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019#code-snippet-1